# Task owner not changing

Tags: tasks

I am facing an issue related to task ownership.
I have a workflow on lead which creates a task when a lead is created.
When the lead is reassigned to other user, task will also be reassigned however, when lead is assigned to queue and then to a user task is assigned to the first user only

lead ownership changed from
user1-> user2 working (task ownership changes from user1 to user2)
user1->queue->user2 not working (task owner is User1)

Is this expected behavior or some issue?
What solutions do I have process builder or trigger?

WF is on lead
Evaluation Criteria: Evaluate the rule when a record is created
Rule Criteria(Lead: Lead StatusEQUALSOpen)
  Workflow Actions -Task

Comment: You need to share the workflow rule formula

Comment: Nick,

That would be expected behaviour as the workflow evaluates the Queue as an owner differently from the Users. If you go into the Workflow formula editor it shows separate fields for the Owner as Case Owner Queue and Case Owner User.

You would need to add either another workflow that looks at the Owner and validates that it is a user - I've used this as a part of it Owner:User.IsActive to check the user is an active user not a queue.

Comment: Updated my question.
Dave - I am not getting you, task ownership changes when the lead/contact owner changes (this is standard functionality) but this is not working when it is a queue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming this is because the task doesn't move with the lead when it is moved to a queue, since queue's can't own tasks (idea [here](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=087300000007HC0AAM)) but stays under the initial owner. When the lead is then reassigned from the queue to the next user the task wouldn't move along with it. One idea would be to create a process in process builder that will run when a lead is moved to a user from a queue and reassign the tasks to the new lead owner.
[image]

Comment: Yes Jenny, I second that. As a workaround, I created a process to reassign task to lead owner, if owner is changed from queue to user.